# what does "standing" means here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> In 2003, a EU peacekeeping force was stationed in FYR Macedonia to stabilize the country after a brief civil war in 2001.  Signalling a determination to play a more active regional security role, the EU now maintains a multinational **standing** ‘ready-response’ force of 1,500 soldiers to deal with strategic and humanitarian crises – in Europe, but also in northern and sub-Saharan Africa.

Does the sentence mean that: EU has ready-to-act forces of 1,500 soldiers? If yes, what is the role/meaning of standing here?

Comment: I'm sure someone will add a detailed answer, but try looking up or googling *standing army* (an army not fighting, but at the ready to fight at a moment's notice).

Comment: Yorgun - Use the block quote markup ">" when inserting block quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dan Bron mentioned in the comments, a "standing" force or army is a group that not currently in combat, but that is prepared and ready to fight as soon as is necessary.

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/standing?s=t) defines "standing" as:

> Continuing in operation, force, use, etc.

You can also say that the force of 1,500 soldiers is **standing by**.

The role of this expression is to emphasize the readiness or preparedness of the force.

Comment: You might add a definition to your answer - [standing](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/standing): "8. going on regularly without change; lasting; permanent"   ⇒ *a standing order*"

Comment: @user3169 Thanks, I added something from Dictionary.com

Comment: @cccg03, sorry to keep hassling you, but you could add the link to dictionary.com to your answer, in addition to copying the relevant section.